# css background: url(); / image not working

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to place a menu icon on my webpage. On my CSS document I use the following code:

```
  .nav-menu-btn{
    background: url(../images/menu-btn.png)no-repeat;
    filter: var(--color-filter);
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
```

I have my css document in a different folder within my project folder, as well as a seperate folder for my images. Any ideas?

I have tried moving the image to my main project file, and every combination of quotes "", and single quotes '' that i can think of. I have also tried using background-image: url(); instead, but nothing has produced any different results

Comment: As you are telling that you have used many folders, once check that the css file is imported correctly or not. You can also debug the issue just by putting `background-color: red` so that you can know exactly where the problem is, css block or any other place.

Comment: yes, I have seperate directories for my css, js, and images. And yes my css file has been imported correctly. Using background-color: red; didn't do anything either. I'm lost

Comment: If that's the case, can you share the html part of it as well

Comment: I think `url(../images/menu-btn.png)no-repeat` must be `url(../images/menu-btn.png) no-repeat`.

Comment: I have tried putting a space between the url and no-repeat, same issue. As for the html portion:  <div class="nav-menu-btn"></div>

Comment: If putting background-color: red made no difference then it looks like that CSS isn’t being picked up. Have you checked in your browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what is setting the CSS for the element?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if I'm seeing this right you are missing double quotation marks inside your url. Try below if that works and let me know. If this doesnt works maybe you are using a wrong path Try to use your website path and see if that works. Please provide your folders on your server how it looks like so everyone can see.

```css
.nav-menu-btn{
    background: url("https://yourwebsite.com/images/menu-btn.png")no-repeat;
    filter: var(--color-filter);
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: It should just work fine without the double quotation marks.

Comment: quotation is an optional but some characters if being used need to be escaped. Try to get the path of your website like above and see if that works for you. I cant see all your code and your path to your server.